# Why is the value of my variable not showing in the render for my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm quite new to REACT, and I feel like this is such a simple solution, but I haven't found anything to help me, so I'd like to try asking myself here.

I have a component where I'm trying to change the text depending on what the location.pathname is. The code looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function PageTitle(props) {

    let location = useLocation();
    let title;

    useEffect(() => {
        let page = location.pathname;
        changeTitleState(page);
    });


    function changeTitleState(page) {
        switch (page) {
            case "/":
                title = "About Me";
                console.log("The title is " + title)
                break;
            case "/portfolio":
                title = "Portfolio";
                console.log("The title is " + title)
                break;
            case "/contact":
                title = "Contact"
                console.log("The title is " + title)
                break;
            default:
                title = "";
                break;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <div className="container my-3 p-3 border border border-info bg-light">
                <div className="d-flex row">
                    <div className="align-items-baseline col-lg-12 text-info">
                        <h1 className="display-4 text-center text-lg-left">{title}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr className="my-3" />
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default PageTitle;
```

I have a variable called "title" with a function to switch the string of that variable and then display it in the render below it. However, it isn't appearing. I thought this might be a scope issue, but I feel I have this correctly in the code, so maybe it's a REACT quirk I'm not familiar with. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need title to be state and update when location.pathname changes

```
let title
```

should be

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
```

And in your  changeTitleState function call setTitle

```
 function changeTitleState(page) {
    switch (page) {
        case "/":
            setTitle("About Me");
            console.log("The title is " + title)
            break;
        case "/portfolio":
          setTitle("Portfolio");
            console.log("The title is " + title)
            break;
        case "/contact":
          setTitle("Contact");
            console.log("The title is " + title)
            break;
        default:
          setTitle("");
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is it, of course I have to use state. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sure. please check off as correct if this answer is what you're looking for.